# Excel Match Function with two Criteria but differing match types

Tags: excel, matching

Basically I am trying to improve a spreadsheet that current uses fixed `IF` functions within IF functions to determine where to find data, then originally used the `VLOOKUP` function to return the appropriate cable cleat size. Where "Cleat Diameter">"Cable Diameter".

I've been using this for a while, however excel quickly runs out of resources with all the remaining calculations being performed. As a result, I've opted to put all data a single table, and try to use the match function to retrieve the necessary row. Then Simply use the `=INDIRECT` function to retrieve data from the appropriate column of the associated row.

Unfortunately I believe the issue relates to the fact that I first need to perform at `MATCH Type 0` (exact match), followed by a `type -1` for the size to identify the next size up that can accommodate a specific cable size.

I've managed a simple lookup on another dataset using (for exact matches):

```
=MATCH($B3,'Current Raw Data'!A:A,0)+ROW('Current Raw Data'!A:A)-1
```

However when I attempt the same thing with two types of matches I get errors. The closest I get it using the following array formula, but it does not work unless the data set is arranged so that the contents of `Cell C3` is the first occurring item in the dataset in `column A:A`:

```
{=MATCH(C3,($B3='Lookup - Cleats'!A:A)*('Lookup - Cleats'!B:B),-1)}
```

Main sheet:

[image]

Dataset Example:

[image]

Comment: `{=MATCH(1,($B3='Lookup - Cleats'!A:A)*('Lookup - Cleats'!B:B = C3),0)}`

Comment: Perfect thank you. The trick was changing your equation to: `{=MATCH(1,($B3='Lookup - Cleats'!A:A)*('Lookup - Cleats'!B:B >= C3),0)}` Then re-arranging the list in ascending order from smallest to biggest size cleats.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With this **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together inside formula bar), you should be able to get your results:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Lookup - Cleats'!C$3:C$26,MATCH($B3&$C3,'Lookup - Cleats'!$A$3:$A$26&'Lookup - Cleats'!$B$3:$B$26,0)),"")
```

I tried my best to use your data setup but maybe miss one or two things that you will need to adjust accordingly.  Let me know if this is not working.